# How to input value in your script deployed to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I have made a script using youtube data api and for the script to properly run the api sends a link to browse in the console and then I have to enter a verification code (gotten after verifying my script) to the console to start the script properly. I have deployed the code in heroku but how to give it input?

Comment: You may have to expose a rest API or you can use a form if you are not frequently input data.

Comment: A form as in by making it a web app then making a form?